# Div with 2 images and a separator

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a button/div that looks like this:

[image]

I've gotten pretty far, but I'm unsure how to align it correctly and add the line separator...

This is my code:

```css
.inflateBtn {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 34px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.inflateIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.inflateBtn svg {
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.brandLogo {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.brandLogo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="inflateBtn">
    <div class="inflateIcon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-wind"><path d="M9.59 4.59A2 2 0 1 1 11 8H2m10.59 11.41A2 2 0 1 0 14 16H2m15.73-8.27A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 19.5 12H2"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="brandLogo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Cjfxurc.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exact, you will have to play around with the numbers, but the idea is not to use margins on the inner two divs, but to use paddings. This way, the inner divs are aligned with the outer one, thus you can add a border.

```css
.inflateBtn {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.inflateIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.inflateBtn svg {
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.brandLogo {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 34px 12px 12px;
}

.brandLogo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="inflateBtn">
    <div class="inflateIcon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-wind"><path d="M9.59 4.59A2 2 0 1 1 11 8H2m10.59 11.41A2 2 0 1 0 14 16H2m15.73-8.27A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 19.5 12H2"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="brandLogo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Cjfxurc.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` to align all of your items easily. Below is the code which does the same.

```css
.inflateBtn {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
}

.inflateIcon {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.inflateBtn svg {
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
}

.brandLogo {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.brandLogo img {
  width: 100px;
}

.separator {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inflateBtn">
    <div class="inflateIcon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-wind"><path d="M9.59 4.59A2 2 0 1 1 11 8H2m10.59 11.41A2 2 0 1 0 14 16H2m15.73-8.27A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 19.5 12H2"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="brandLogo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Cjfxurc.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```